# colspan like feature for spring form textarea

Tags: forms, spring, jsp

How can I get colspan like feature in a form:textarea in spring form tag?

This is my current code:

```
<td><html:textarea  rows="5" cols="60" path="comment" /></td>
```

There are total 5 columns in the table. I would like to have the label in the first column and textarea in the remaining 4 colums. How can I achieve this?

Comment: "Colspan like"? How about applying `colspan` itself to the enclosing `td`? [IIs this what you want?](http://jsfiddle.net/A4uUU/1)

Comment: oh great, I was trying to put it inside the textarea.

Comment: If it solves your problem, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need a "colspan-like" solution but `colspan` itself. Note that what you want to span is a table cell, not the textarea. Therefore, you must use the attribute on the enclosing `td` element.

Text areas in HTML have their own layout of rows and columns but it's completely unrelated to HTML tables. A `colspan` attribute on a `textarea` simply doesn't make sense.

Here's a piece of HTML code that does the trick.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>Z</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td colspan="2"><textarea cols="60" rows="3"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's [a working example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A4uUU/1), styled with CSS to make the structure more visible.